# scrollable content within tab content view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create an interface that is a tabbed view. my form is in one tab and the results will be in another tab.  I am having difficulty in getting the form to scroll down so that I can access the data off screen.  Tab1 below is the content I want to be scrollable.  Am I using the wrong type of container to hold my form and that is why I cannot scroll it down as I enter data into my form fields?  Can you offer any suggestions as to what I am missing or doing wrong please?

my main tab gui xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/tab1"/>
            <include layout="@layout/tab2"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Tab1 -- this is where I want the content to be scrollable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@layout/tab1" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="3" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="2" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_fn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_ln" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_ssn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" android:maxLength="9999"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_class" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/search_class_all"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_class_comm"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_class_med"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_status" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/search_status_all" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_status_avail" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_status_emp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/view1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

tab2 -- once the search is complete the results will be displayed here.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@layout/tab2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/view2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tab you want to scroll, you need to use `<ScrollView>` instead of `<LinearLayout>`. Or, create the `<ScrollView>` as the first item in your `<LinearLayout>`, and then all your scrollable content goes inside the `<ScrollView>`.

For example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@layout/tab1">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView>...
        <EditText>...
        <OtherObjects>...

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```